# What is the starting bias for different factions?

Tags: civilization-5

The starting bias is the setting (you can disable it in game set up) which allows your civilization to have a starting point similar to its original historical location. Like for instance if you play for ottomans you would start in a desert or if you play for iroquois you would start in a forest. So what is this bias for other factions?

Also, how does it work, is the part of the map generated specifically for a certain civilization, or is it generated randomly and then the best fitting spots found?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is based on the comments and data inside the XML file (`Assets/Gameplay/XML/Civilizations/CIV5Civilizations.xml`).

The start bias just chooses the location on the map, it does not influence map generation itself.

There are 4 different start bias categories, a civilization can only belong in one category:

- Start along Ocean
- Start along River
- Start in specific Region
- Avoid specific Region

The start biases for the specific civilizations are the following:

```
Civilization    Start bias
---------------------------------------
England         Ocean
Ottoman         Ocean
Arabia          Desert
Aztec           Jungle
India           Grass
Iroquois        Forest
Russia          Tundra
Egypt           Avoid Jungle and Forest
Siam            Avoid Forest
Songhai         Avoid Tundra

DLC Civ         Start bias
---------------------------------------
Mongolia        Plains
Spain           Ocean
Inca            Hills
Polynesia       Ocean
```

Comment: @Fabian, great answer, but the list isn't full, what about the others?

Comment: All others don't have a start bias, as far as I can tell.

Comment: It might be possible that "start bias" also refers to the placement of natural wonders; I noticed once that when I was the Japanese, I spawned very close to Mt. Fuji.

Comment: @Ken There is nothing in the XML suggesting that natural wonders play a role in civ placement. I would guess that it was just chance in your case.

Comment: Are you a developer of this game, who would be in a position to confirm that XML is the sole driver of the game's logic and behavior? Also, have you fully investigated the XML for the wonders? It might be such that the wonders don't play a role in civ placement, but the placement of civs might play a role in wonder placement (dependency reversed from your wording).

Comment: In short, I don't think the starting location is the sole attribute modified via the `Start Bias`; it's "start" bias, not "starting location" bias.

Comment: @ken I'm not a civ developer (AFAIK noone here is). The start bias XML is pretty well documented and natural wonders aren't mentioned in this documentation. So, in absence of any further information from the Civ 5 developers, I would think that this is a pretty reasonable base to conclude that natural wonders have no influence on start bias calculations.

Comment: @ken I have not found the link specifically between Mount Fuji and Japanese civilization start bias, but if you look at [Mount Fuji placement requirements](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/96479/24745) you shall see that is needs to be placed on the medium-sized island (not on largest landmass, not on island too small), which could be similar requirement for Japanese starting location if such requirement exists.

Comment: @MadScientist, to respond to your last comment: they are not, indeed. Candidate locations for natural wonders are selected after the civ starts were already placed (though you would not necessarily know this from XML-files alone). See link in my previous comment on how it is done.

Answer (score -1):

You can find a full list here
http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Starting_bias_(Civ5)

Comment: Please summarize the linked page's information here.  That way, it saves people a click, and ensures your answer is still good if the site ever goes down.