# Where does Civilization V prefer to place each civ at the start?

Tags: civilization-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Civ 5, What is the starting bias for different factions?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9805/in-civ-5-what-is-the-starting-bias-for-different-factions)

If I recall correctly, there are some preferences the game will take into account when attempting to place you on a random map, e.g. Aztecs will start near jungles, Egyptians will be in deserts, but I can't find those rules--what are they?